# Simplify $[14]_8 \oplus[12]_8\oplus[31]_8$, where $[\cdot]$ denotes a residue class mod 8

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

> Simplify the following:
>   $$[14]_8 \oplus[12]_8\oplus[31]_8$$

I have the following:
\begin{align}&[14]_8 \oplus[12]_8\oplus[31]_8 \\ &=[14+12+31]_8 \\&=[57]_8 \\&=[57 + 8k  \ | k \in \mathbb{Z}] \\&=[1]_8\end{align}

Is this correct?

Comment: Is this a new thing to use $\oplus$ as modular addition? It's typically used to mean the direct sum of groups or modules.

Comment: The textbook we use makes use of $\oplus$ in this way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.  Addition and multiplication both "play nicely" in modular arithmetic.